# Variables in heredoc inside object in PHP

Tags: php

The following php code will throw an error:

```
class Foo{
    public $bar = <<<EOF
         {$this->foobar}
EOF;
    public $foobar = "123";

   public function echoBar(){
         echo $this->bar;
   }
}
```

It doesn't even have to be in brackets, any attempt at variable substitution throws an error.

Can someone explain why? Putting the heredoc inside a function fixes the error, but I was wondering what causes this.

Version of php shell is Zend Engine v2.3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer [is here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) in the official PHP docs:

> **Heredocs can not be used for initializing class properties.** Since PHP
>   5.3, this limitation is valid only for heredocs containing variables.